# Is it possible to describe existing resources in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a scenario where I want to enable flow-logs for all the existing VPCs(by existing I mean ones which are not created by Cloud-formation stack) which are there in my AWS Account. For these I would need to describe all the existing VPC from my AWS Account(let say region specific) and get their Vpc-id which then I will fed it to create-flow-log.
Is it even possible to describe existing resources through Cloud Formation Stack, because I didn't find any AWS Documentation for this purpose? Is there any other possibility by which this can be done and still using Cloud-Formation?

Comment: This is probably not something that would be done through CloudFormation. Normally, CloudFormation is used to deploy infrastructure in a known configuration that can be re-used and re-deployed in future. If CloudFormation initially deployed these VPCs, then it would simply be a matter of changing the parameter in the CloudFormation template and then _updating_ the stack. Otherwise, it is more appropriate to do it _outside of_ CloudFormation (eg using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or a program).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Malay - It is possible to refer existing resources which are not created by CFN. But, it's not possible to modify them.

Here's an example to take the existing VPC IDs as an input parameter:

```
List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>
An array of VPC IDs, such as vpc-a123baa3, vpc-b456baa3.
```

Hope it helps.